# How do I make an array element an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap` class that instantiates a variable "table" of type `Object[]` to `Object[cap]`, where cap is equal to 10 in testing. I have the following put method in the `HashMap` class:

```
public void put(K key, V value){
    HashEntry<K, V> newEntry = new HashEntry<K, V>(key, value);
    location = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % capacity;
    //System.out.println(location);

    if(table[location] == null){
        table[location] = new ArrayList<HashEntry<K, V>>();
        table[location] = newEntry;
        numItems++;
    }
    else {
        table[location] = newEntry;
    }
}
```

In order for the `ArrayList` to work, I should be using `table[location].add(newEntry)`, not `table[location] = newEntry`. However, if I use the former, I get the message "The method `add(HashEntry<K,V>)` is undefined for the type `Object`." When I use the latter, I of course cannot get the correct output as there is not a "`bucket`" from which to retrieve info. I prefer using `ArrayList` to a 2-dimensional array because I don't get `2D arrays` at all! Any help is appreciated as I have been going in a circle all day trying a million different things.

Comment: where/how are you defining `table` ?

Comment: Did you try declaring table as an array of Lists? Like "List[] table;"

Comment: Object[] table; then in the constructor, table = new Object[cap];

Comment: List[] table causes other issues, but solves the .add issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(table[location] == null){
    table[location] = new ArrayList<HashEntry<K, V>>();
    table[location] = newEntry;
    numItems++;
}
else {
    table[location] = newEntry;
}
```

This is just wrong.  It should be:

```
if(table[location] == null){
    table[location] = new ArrayList<HashEntry<K, V>>();
}
table[location].add(newEntry);
```

The table is an array of references to `ArrayList<HashEntry<K,V>>`  Once you have located the bucket you want (and initialized it if needed), you want to *add* the new entry to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: I certainly see your point and I've changed the code. Thanks for that! However, I'm still left with the more difficult issue of the error message, "The method `add(HashEntry<K,V>)` is undefined for the type Object."

Answer (score -1):

One way to directly assign elements of Array to an ArrayList are:

```
 String array[]={"Abc","Def"};
 List<String> list=Arrays.asList(array);
```

Second way is to loop through the array elements through for loop and then assign them to arrayList as:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length'i++)
{
     list.add(arr[i]);
}
```